# R rank ties.method = "min" with different number of observations per grouping

Tags: r

Let's imagine we have one observation for four quarters of the years 2013 to 2023. We have this for a number of different categories - for simplicity purposes, let's take 5 and call them A, B, C, D, and E. Each category takes one value per year. A category must not appear in all quarters of a year and categories can take the same values.

We would like to get a new column with the rank for each category within a given year. The highest value per year should get rank 1 and in case of ties we would like to see what `rank(x, ties.method = "min")` does.

Below is a reproducible example and some problems are described. I am mainly interested in elegant {tidyverse} codes.

```
dat <- tibble(
  year = rep(c(2013:2023), 4),
  quart = rep(c(1:4), 11)
  ) %>% 
  crossing(vv = rep(LETTERS[1:5])) %>% 
  arrange(year, vv) %>% 
  mutate(
    rn = row_number(),
    value = c(rep(10000, 8), rep(c(round(rnorm(53, 100, 20), 3)), each = 4))
  ) 

## works if equal number of `quart` for each `year` and `vv`
ranked_1 <- dat %>% 
  group_by(year, quart) %>% 
  mutate(
    r1 = rank(desc(value), ties.method = "min"),
    r2 = dense_rank(desc(value))
  ) %>% 
  arrange(r1)

## as we have two rank 1 for `year == "2013"` the next rank we wish to see
## for `year == "2013"` is rank 3 and not rank 2 - ok, so far
ranked_1 %>% filter(year == "2013" & (r1 == 1 | r1 == 2 | r1 == 3))

## problem if no longer equal number of `quart` for each `year` and `vv`
dat %>%
  filter(row_number() != 2) %>% 
  group_by(year, quart) %>% 
  mutate(
    r1 = rank(desc(value), ties.method = "min"),
    r2 = dense_rank(desc(value))
  ) %>% 
  arrange(r1) %>% 
  filter(year == "2013" & (r1 == 1 | r1 == 2 | r1 == 3))

## `group_by(year)` does also not what we want
ranked_3 <- dat %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(
    r1 = rank(desc(value), ties.method = "min"),
    r2 = dense_rank(desc(value))
  ) %>% 
  arrange(r1)

## as we have two rank 1 for `year == "2013"` the next rank we wish to see
## for `year == "2013"` is rank 3 and not rank 5 and not rank 2
ranked_3 %>% filter((r1 == 2 | r1 == 3 | r1 == 4))
ranked_3 %>% filter(year == "2013" & r2 == 2)

## this does the ranking job - can we get this ranking on the whole 
## `dat` (without intermediate object and joining)?
dat %>% 
  distinct(year, vv, value) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(r1 = rank(desc(value), ties.method = "min")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(year, r1)
```

Comment: Are you still interested in help? If so, could you add `set.seed()` to make reproducible, and include what the final output should look like in the end?